# Do not Disturb does not turn off according to schedule

Tags: ios, do-not-disturb

I searched around but I felt like I am the only person who had this problem.

I am running 17.1.2 but this problem have been around since day 1. I have "Do not disturb" enabled with a schedule to have a quiet night until 7AM. But at least once a week, the "Do not disturb" does not turn off in the morning, well into my day. I look up online and everyone just talking about how "Do not disturb" is stuck and cannot be turned off. I can turn it off manually. But problem return within a week.

What could I do to fix it?